# Field to pick-list selection

Tags: validation-rule, fields, dependent-picklist, admin

Hi I need a favor regarding pick-list selection.

for example: I have a **Location** object. In Location object I have (County name) field. I created *county 1, county 2, county 3*.   And I have another object **Candidates**. In **Candidates** object I have created a record with name **County Location**. here in this **County Location** record you get options of *County 1, 2, 3* with the a lookup relation with **Location object**.  In same **Candidates** object I have a pick list with hospital names. *Hospital 1, 2, 3*. When I choose *County 1* option in **County Location** record field, I would like to see *hospital 1* option in pick-list.
Please help me with suggestions, how can I achieve this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: I tried and did with field dependencies, but i wanna achieve this through lookup field I tried with validation rules, but I am new to it. If give me some suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it in standard edit layout. You have to create a visualforce page for Candidate object to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any option by using validation rules I can do it?

Comment: Nope, you won't be able to do it using validation rules.